# Как в htaccess запретить доступ к конкретным страницам всем кроме моего IP?

Tags: .htaccess

Имею блог на Джумле. На сайте нет регистрации и авторизации, но у джумлы есть конкретные ссылки для доступа к ним, например авторизация: /index.php?option=com_users&view=login

Хочу запретить всем доступ к этим страницам, кроме своего IP. Сколько ни гуглил, нашел только одно решение, но оно не работает вообще.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "index.php?option=com_users&view=login" deny
Allow from 'мой айпи'
Deny from env=deny
```

Мне нужно подобное решение, только я пропишу не один такой URL, а не сколько.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удивляет, что никто не может ответить на такой простой вопрос. Для не программиста, пришлось кучу времени потратить чтобы перелопатить различные сайты и форму. В итоге вот ответ:

Если ссылка имеет Get запрос (index.php?option=com_users&view=login) пишем так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_users($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)view=login($|&)
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^255\.255\.255\.255$ (Тут ваш айпи)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

Если ссылка имеет нормальную структуру (/wp-admin), то так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^255\.255\.255\.255$ (Тут ваш айпи)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Так наоборот же. Сначала запретить, потом разрешить.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from IP1
```